# Comparator not comparing values correctly

Tags: java, list, comparator

I have this comparator that   compares the marks of each subjects overal mark and sorts them from highest to lowest. the only problem is that the subject List is bound within a student object. so for each student there are many subjects. the overal marks are of type double. the comparator isnt working desired.

```
public class RankComparator implements Comparator<Subject> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Subject s1, Subject s2) {

            if (s1.getoveralMark() < s2.getoveralMark())
                return -1;
            if (s1.getoveralMark() > s2.getoveralMark())
                return 1;

            return 0;

        }

    }
```

UPDATE : I have added the following code but its still not sorting the subjects by highest overalMark.

```
 for (Student student : studentList) {
                // if (subj.subjectName.contains("English")) {

                for (Subject subj : student.subject) {
                    Collections.sort(student.subject, new RankComparator());
                    System.out.println(subj.overalMark);

                }


Collections.sort(studentList, compareByAllSubjects());

        for (Student student : studentList) {
            System.out.println(student.firstName);
            for (Subject subk : student.subject) {

                System.out.println(subk.subjectName);
                System.out.println(subk.overalMark);

            }
        }

        // }
    }

    private static Comparator<Student> compareBySubject(final int index) {
        return new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student student0, Student student1) {
                Subject subject0 = student0.subject.get(index);
                Subject subject1 = student1.subject.get(index);
                if (subject0.getSubjectName() == subject1.getSubjectName()) {
                    double mark0 = subject0.getoveralMark();
                    double mark1 = subject1.getoveralMark();
                    return Double.compare(mark0, mark1);
                }
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    private static double computeMaxMark(List<Subject> subjects) {
        double max = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Subject subject : subjects) {
            max = Math.max(max, subject.getoveralMark());
        }
        return max;
    }

    private static Comparator<Student> compareByAllSubjects() {
        return new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student student0, Student student1) {
                double mark0 = computeMaxMark(student0.getSubject());
                double mark1 = computeMaxMark(student1.getSubject());
                return Double.compare(mark0, mark1);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: *the comparator isnt working desired.* - Can you post your *Desire* too?

Comment: And *how it is not working*?

Comment: @Adam Arold for example you have the values 45.6, 50, 52.3,75.3   it will sort it  the following: 75.3, 75.3, 52.3, 52.3

Comment: Why are you iterating over the subject list to sort it? That's totally unnecessary. If you need to iterate it for other things, sort it first then iterate over the sorted collection.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist because each student contains a list of subjects

Comment: So you want to sort the *subjects* of *one* student according to the mark that the student achieved in the subjects? Or do you want to sort the *students* based on the mark that they achieved in *one* subject?

Comment: @user3423698: But for each student, you're iterating over his subjects. This is unnecessary.

Comment: @Marco13 I want to sort the students based on the mark they achieved in one subject

Comment: @user3423698: if you want to sort students, then you need a comparator which compares students, not subjects. And you need to sort the studentList, not the subject list of each student. The comparator must get the English mark of student 1, the English mark of student 2, and return the comparison of the two marks.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the comments, you want to sort the students based on the mark they achieved in one subject. In this case, you don't need a `Comparator<Subject>` but a `Comparator<Student>` - namely, a comparator that compares Students.

However, this comparator has to "know" according to which subject the students should be compared. In this case, it might be necessary to know whether all students have the *same* subjects, or whether the sets of subjects may be different for each student. If they may be different, one has to think about how the sorting should handle a student that does *not* have the subject according to which the students should be sorted.

However, a general approach for creating comparators that sort the students based on the marks that they achieved in a particular subject is shown in this example :

(EDIT: Added another sorting criterion, this seems to be a guessing game....)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class StudentSorting
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random(0);
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            Student student = new Student("Student"+i);
            student.addSubject(new Subject("A", random.nextInt(6)));
            student.addSubject(new Subject("B", random.nextInt(6)));
            student.addSubject(new Subject("C", random.nextInt(6)));
            students.add(student);
        }

        for (int s=0; s<3; s++)
        {
            System.out.println("Students compared by subject "+s);
            Collections.sort(students, compareBySubject(s));
            for (Student student : students)
            {
                System.out.println("    "+student);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Students compared all subjects");
        Collections.sort(students, compareByAllSubjects());
        for (Student student : students)
        {
            System.out.println("    "+student);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Creates a comparator that compares students by the overall mark
     * that they achieved in the subject with the given index
     *
     * @param index The index of the subject
     * @return The comparator
     */
    private static Comparator<Student> compareBySubject(final int index)
    {
        return new Comparator<Student>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student student0, Student student1)
            {
                Subject subject0 = student0.getSubject(index);
                Subject subject1 = student1.getSubject(index);
                double mark0 = subject0.getOverallMark();
                double mark1 = subject1.getOverallMark();
                return Double.compare(mark0, mark1);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Creates a comparator that compares students by the overall mark
     * that they achieved in any subject
     *
     * @return The comparator
     */
    private static Comparator<Student> compareByAllSubjects()
    {
        return new Comparator<Student>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student student0, Student student1)
            {
                double mark0 = computeMaxMark(student0.getSubjects());
                double mark1 = computeMaxMark(student1.getSubjects());
                return Double.compare(mark0, mark1);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Computes the maximum overall mark of the given subjects
     *
     * @param subjects The subjects
     * @return THe maximum mark
     */
    private static double computeMaxMark(List<Subject> subjects)
    {
        double max = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Subject subject : subjects)
        {
            max = Math.max(max, subject.getOverallMark());
        }
        return max;
    }

}


class Subject
{
    private final String name;
    private final double mark;

    Subject(String name, double mark)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    double getOverallMark()
    {
        return mark;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name+"("+mark+")";
    }
}

class Student
{
    private final String name;
    private final List<Subject> subjects;

    Student(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    }

    void addSubject(Subject subject)
    {
        subjects.add(subject);
    }

    Subject getSubject(int index)
    {
        return subjects.get(index);
    }

    List<Subject> getSubjects()
    {
        return subjects;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name+" with "+subjects;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to sort students with the highest overal mark for each subject

Comment: @user3423698 That's what the code is doing. The lack of precision in your questions is disturbing. However, I added another sorting criterion (and updated the code in the answer). If this is not what you want, then **provide an example of what you want**

Comment: @user3423698 I give up.